# Edit SVG file with PHP

Tags: php, svg, pear

I want to open and manipulate a SVG graphic with PHP. I found there is a PEAR class *XML_SVG*. This looks great, but seems to only create new files. I did not find any **load_svg()** function that loads an existing SVG from file or string.

Is there a way to load an existing SVG file and then manipulate it with Pear XML_SVG?

Comment: Doesn't look like it does it?

Comment: It looks like there are a number of libraries that do this based on quick Google search for `edit SVG with PHP`, perhaps one of them might meet your needs.

Comment: I assume that you need something like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41264017/php-svg-editing

Answer (score 0):

There is not. I went through all the files.

https://github.com/pear/XML_SVG