# PHP SVG editing

Tags: php, xml, dom, svg, simplexml

For example I am trying to read the style block from an svg, I can get the type but not the string.

```
$svgTemplate = new SimpleXMLElement($_POST['SvgTemplateImport']);
$svgTemplate->registerXPathNamespace('svg', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
$svgTemplate->registerXPathNamespace('xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');

//I tried a bunch of things and this how far I got
$test[] = $svgTemplate->xpath('/svg:svg/svg:style');
$test[] = $result[0][0]['type'];

var_dump($test);
```

How to retrieve the style string?
How to set the style string?
How to copy a group and change attributes on it? (like translate x and y)?

I also want to change the resolution and viewbox of the svg among other things, but I will be able to figure those out from the answer.

Thanks.

EDIT1: 
See my svg: I commented what I want to achieve.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" width="460px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 460 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 460 200;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">/* new style */</style>
<!-- I did cut the unrelevant parts out-->
<symbol id="MoonFull" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M50,99.33C22.8,99.33,0.67,77.2,0.67,50S22.8,0.67,50,0.67S99.33,22.8,99.33,50S77.2,99.33,50,99.33   z"/>
    <path style="fill:#231F20;" d="M50,1.35c26.83,0,48.65,21.82,48.65,48.65S76.83,98.65,50,98.65S1.35,76.83,1.35,50   S23.17,1.35,50,1.35 M50,0C22.39,0,0,22.39,0,50s22.39,50,50,50s50-22.39,50-50S77.61,0,50,0L50,0z"/>
</symbol>
<symbol id="Star" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path id="Star" style="fill:#00FF00;" d="M50,3.58L62.5,39H100L70.83,60.95l10.42,34.93L50,74.81L18.75,95.53l10.42-34.51L0,39  h37.5L50,3.58z"/>
</symbol>
<g id="TemplateForm">
    <g id="twd">
        <rect id="twdCanvas" x="7.3" y="9.32" class="st0" width="263.03" height="72"/>
        <text id="twdWeekdayshorttext" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 249.5817 41.9174)"><tspan x="0" y="0" class="st2 st3">C</tspan><tspan x="-1.2" y="29.13" class="st2 st3">S</tspan></text>
        <text id="twdDatenumber" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 41.5544 69.5698)" class="st5 st6">26</text>
        <line id="twdDivider" class="st7" x1="126.49" y1="9.32" x2="126.49" y2="81.32"/>
        <g id="twdText">
            <text id="twdTextLine3" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 135.0475 28.1718)" class="st2 st8">1234567890abcdef12345</text>
            <text id="twdTextLine2" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 135.0475 41.5319)" class="st2 st8">1234567890abcdef12345</text>
            <text id="twdTextLine1" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 135.0475 54.892)" class="st2 st8">1234567890abcdef12345</text>
            <text id="twdTextLine0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 135.0475 68.252)" class="st2 st8">1234567890abcdef12345</text>
        </g>
        <line id="twdDateNumAliignerLeft" class="st0" x1="120.02" y1="17.39" x2="120.02" y2="72.07"/>
        <rect id="twdBoxStar" x="15.68" y="19.75" class="st0" width="21" height="21"/>
        <rect id="twdBoxText" x="132.49" y="17.39" class="st0" width="107.92" height="54.68"/>
        <rect id="twdBoxMoon" x="15.68" y="49.15" class="st0" width="21" height="21"/>
    </g>
    <g id="tcl">
        <rect id="tclCanvas" x="7.3" y="153.31" class="st0" width="263.03" height="36"/>
        <line id="tclDivider" class="st7" x1="126.49" y1="153.31" x2="126.49" y2="189.31"/>
        <text id="tclYear" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 59.1393 183.5269)" class="st2 st9">YYYY</text>
        <text id="tclMonthname" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 130.9372 182.7798)" class="st2 st10">monthname</text>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="result"><!-- this group will be generated -->
    <!-- this is made from: #twd and added transformation-->
    <g id="result1" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 249.5817 41.9174)">
        <rect id="twdCanvas" x="7.3" y="9.32" class="st0" width="263.03" height="72"/>
        <!-- all the texts will be canged -->
        <text id="twdWeekdayshorttext" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 249.5817 41.9174)"><tspan x="0" y="0" class="st2 st3">C</tspan><tspan x="-1.2" y="29.13" class="st2 st3">S</tspan></text>
        <text id="twdDatenumber" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 41.5544 69.5698)" class="st5 st6">26</text>
        <line id="twdDivider" class="st7" x1="126.49" y1="9.32" x2="126.49" y2="81.32"/>
        <g id="twdText">
            <text id="twdTextLine3" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 135.0475 28.1718)" class="st2 st8">changed this</text>
            <text id="twdTextLine2" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 135.0475 41.5319)" class="st2 st8">changed this</text>
            <text id="twdTextLine1" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 135.0475 54.892)" class="st2 st8">changed this</text>
            <text id="twdTextLine0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 135.0475 68.252)" class="st2 st8">changed this</text>
        </g>
        <line id="twdDateNumAliignerLeft" class="st0" x1="120.02" y1="17.39" x2="120.02" y2="72.07"/>
        <rect id="twdBoxText" x="132.49" y="17.39" class="st0" width="107.92" height="54.68"/>

        <!-- this: <rect id="twdBoxStar" x="15.68" y="19.75" class="st0" width="21" height="21"/> to: -->
        <use x="132.49" y="17.39" width="21" height="21" xlink:href="#Star" /><!-- how can I chnage the fill color? -->

        <!-- this: <rect id="twdBoxMoon" x="15.68" y="49.15" class="st0" width="21" height="21"/> to: -->
        <use x="15.68" y="49.15" width="21" height="21" xlink:href="#MoonFull" />
    </g>
    <!-- and so on... the end I have to adjust the viewbox and resolution-->
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: _"How to copy a group and change attributes on it?"_ - do you mean a group of elements?

Comment: an svg group: <g id="something"> ... </g>, and make it <g id="something1" transform="...">...</g> I guess the same method applies to all tags that's why i asked that example. Sorry cant edit comments:(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Modifying Existing Structure

```
$svg_data = <<<'SVG'
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <svg:style>
    circle { fill: orange; stroke: black; }
  </svg:style>
  <svg:g id="group-a" stroke="green" fill="white" stroke-width="5">
     <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="15"/>
     <circle cx="40" cy="25" r="15"/>
  </svg:g>
  <svg:g id="group-b" stroke="red" fill="blue" stroke-width="1">
     <circle cx="10" cy="80" r="15"/>
  </svg:g>
</svg>
SVG;

$svgTemplate = new SimpleXMLElement($svg_data);
$svgTemplate->registerXPathNamespace('svg', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');

// How to retrieve the style string
$style = $svgTemplate->xpath('svg:style');
printf("Original style:\n%s\n\n", (string)$style[0]);

// How to set the style string
$children = $svgTemplate->children('svg', true);
$children->style = '/* new style */';

// How to copy a group and change attributes on it (like translate x and y)
$group_a = $svgTemplate->xpath('svg:g[@id="group-a"]');
if (isset($group_a[0])) {
  $group_a[0]->addAttribute('transform', 'translate(30) rotate(45 50 50)');
}

printf("Modified XML:\n%s\n", $svgTemplate->asXML());
```

*Output*

```
Original style:

    circle { fill: orange; stroke: black; }


Modified XML:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <svg:style>/* new style */</svg:style>
  <svg:g id="group-a" stroke="green" fill="white" stroke-width="5" transform="translate(30) rotate(45 50 50)">
     <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="15"/>
     <circle cx="40" cy="25" r="15"/>
  </svg:g>
  <svg:g id="group-b" stroke="red" fill="blue" stroke-width="1">
     <circle cx="10" cy="80" r="15"/>
  </svg:g>
</svg>
```

**Explanations**

The node values are fetched by means of [casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) of the `SimpleXMLElement` object to string. This is possible because `SimpleXMLElement` implements `__toString` method.

Since the `children` method returns the node objects by reference, you can modify the original structure by modifying the value returned by this method. Note, you should pass the registered namespace to the `children` method when appropriate.

In order to add an attribute you need to fetch the node (using `xpath` method, for instance) and call `addAttribute` method in context of this node.

The methods of `SimpleXMLElement` (`xpath`, `children`, and `attributes`, for instance) return a set of matching elements as `SimpleXMLElement` objects. You can access them either by index (e.g. `$style[0]`), or by name (`$children->style`). You can also iterate them using `foreach`.

## Cloning, Modifying, and Appending the Nodes

As far as I can see, it is impossible to append a `SimpleXMLElement` node to the document without doing the deep copy manually. You can make a deep copy by iterating the nodes recursively and calling the `addChild` method. But there is an easy way to perform this using the DOM extension:

```
$svg = new SimpleXMLElement($svg_data);
$svg->registerXPathNamespace('svg', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');

$g_tpl = $svg->xpath('svg:g[@id="TemplateForm"]');
if (!isset($g_tpl[0])) {
  die("#TemplateForm group not found\n");
}

$g_res = clone $g_tpl[0];
$g_res['id'] = 'result';

$g_twd = $g_res->g[0];
$g_twd['id'] = 'result1';
$g_twd['transform'] = 'matrix(1 0 0 1 249.5817 41.9174)';

// Change the rest of the nodes in similar manner.
// Then add $g_res to the root node. You will need DOM extension for this.
$dom_res = dom_import_simplexml($g_res);
$dom_svg = dom_import_simplexml($svg);
$dom_svg->appendChild($dom_res);

echo $svg->asXML();
```

## Consider Using DOM Extension

Generally, if you need to perform complex DOM manipulations on relatively small documents (such as SVG), use DOM extension instead of SimpleXML.

**Example**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($svg_data);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('svg', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');

$g_res = $doc->createElement('g');
$g_res->setAttribute('id', 'result');

$g_twd_list = $xpath->query('svg:g[@id="TemplateForm"]/svg:g[@id="twd"]');

$g_twd = clone $g_twd_list[0];
$g_twd->setAttribute('id', 'result1');
$g_twd->setAttribute('transform', 'matrix(1 0 0 1 249.5817 41.9174)');
$g_res->appendChild($g_twd);

$doc->firstChild->appendChild($g_res);
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

Comment: Do I need to include the <<<'SVG' part in the string, I get it from POST? I want to copy(clone) the the group (its a template group) and insert it to another group(result layer), and modify values and attributes on it, and this runs in a loop. I don't have "group-b" in the beginning.

Comment: @z4k, of course you don't need the here document. Just store your SVG string into `$svg_data` variable, e.g. `$svg_data = $_POST['SvgTemplateImport'];`. I've put the sample XML input for clarity.

Comment: So far so good, how to select where to clone the group? How to change the text values nested down in the group afterwards? Can't "$children" be used for all of this? I have all the ids and the structure is known, I don't need to find groups with id, its a fixed structure. How to do something like : $children->groupId->otherGroupId->textValueById? How can I var dump $children, it should have the whole svg, is this right?

Comment: Fetch the `g` using `xpath` method as shown in the answer. You can iterate `children()` and the nested children using `foreach`, or by accessing the nodes with `[]` (for node set) and `->` (for a node) operators. `var_dump()` on `SimpleXMLElement` doesn't show the values actually stored within the object, - you should access the nodes and attributes via the methods described in the answer. With `var_dump($object)` you can only figure out whether `$object` represents a set of nodes, or a single node.

Comment: I thought I got it, but no. Can you post an example from my svg I added to the question? Clone and change 1 value and 1 attrib. See <g id="result">. Thank You for your effort and time.

Comment: Your answer just change an attrib on the group does not copy the group anywhere, as I understand it. I need to create a new group at another place and change the attribs and values there.

Comment: @z4k, I have added _Cloning, Modifying, and Appending the Nodes_ section

Comment: How can I reference g#templateForm/g#twe. I only want to copy one of the groups from the TemplateForm at once(I cut the rest out from the example), and inserting all of them under g#result. I have tried 'svg:g[@id="TemplateForm"]/g[@id="twe"]', which did not work.

Comment: Try svg:g[@id="TemplateForm"]/svg:g[@id="twe"]

Comment: The "svg:" was missing, but now I create result and put the #twd in and modify the first existing group. What I would like as a result: <g id="result"><g id="result1" transform="...">content of #TemplateForm/#twd</g>... g#result2, g#result3...</g>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131205/discussion-between-ruslan-osmanov-and-z4k).